# Rewrite rule .php to .swf NGINX

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm triying to make a rewrite rule with NGINX to rewrite my file `serveClient.php` to `serveClient.swf`.
Also, I want to pass every `$_GET` parameter.
**For example** accessing to `serveClient.swf?test123` will be like if I go to `serveClient.php?test123`
 and accessing to `serveClient.swf` will be like if I go to `serveClient.php`

Here's what I've tried, but I have a **404** error

```
location test/ {
    rewrite serveClient.swf?^(.*)$ serveClient.php?$1;
}
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` and anything following it (the query string) is not considered as part of the `rewrite` directive's regex.

However, by default (unless you append a `?`), `rewrite` will append the existing query string to the rewritten URI. So this should suffice:

```
rewrite ^(.*)/serveClient\.swf$ $1/serveClient.php;
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Also, prefix locations should begin with a `/`, like:

```
location /test { ... }
location /test/ { ... }
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.